# How to use value from modelin Thymeleaf view?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a java model like this:

```
    public class UserModel {
        private String firstName;
        ....
    }
```

how can i display this value(`firstname`) in the html view handled by thymeleaf?

thanks for any help

Comment: Read Thymeleaf documentation please https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a parse function that has this stucture

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("firstName", firstName);[...]
```

In you html template youl need to refer to the just defined context variable firstName like if you'd have to refer to a javascript variable, for example

```
th:text="${firstName}"></h2>
```